# Warning: require_once:Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, wampserver, fatal-error

can someone help me for better and the simplest explaination for my problem.
This is my problem...
this is my coding

```
<?php require_once('Connections/key1.php'); ?>
```

can someone help??

Comment: It means that `Connections/key1.php` does not exist. Or `key1.php` exists in a different location.

Comment: There are about 500+ questions like this. **DO A SEARCH**

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the file key1.php exists somewhere.
2. make sure that you are pointing to that 'somewhere' in your require_once statement.
3. make sure that key1.php is not throwing any errors.

The best way to check key1 is to turn error checking on and running the script directly from the browser.
Add this to the top of the key1.php after the opening php tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, you might want to add a simple

```
echo "Hello";
```

After the error reporting to see if that gets echoed when you run from the browser. If it does not, and no errors show, you have a compile-time error that error reporting cannot catch. Check your code carefully.

Capitalization counts, so if the file is the connections folder, make sure that it is Connections and not connections.